# Propel: newbie problems with a criteria. Trying to debug

Tags: php, criteria, propel

I have this criteria propel.

```
public static function getPrenotazioniAttive($id_utente)
{

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(self::USER_ID, 18793 );
$result = self::doSelect($c);

}
```

After that i add this:

```
echo $c->toString();
```

that shows:

```
 Criteria: SQL (may not be complete): SELECT FROM `prenotazione` WHERE prenotazione.USER_ID=:p1 Params: prenotazione.USER_ID => 18793
```

Then i call the method before this way:

```
    $prenotazioni = PrenotazionePeer::getPrenotazioniAttive($this->getUser());  

    var_dump($prenotazioni);
    die("entro");
```

that creates/execute the SQL clause below.

```
 SELECT IFNULL(SUM(prenotazione.VALUTAZIONE),0) AS somma, 
 COUNT(*) AS numero 
 FROM `prenotazione` 
 WHERE prenotazione.USER_ID=18793
```

that clause (if i go to phpmyadmin) retrives a row from the table.

My problem: `var_dump($prenotazioni);` just return null, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The `getPrenotazioniAttive` function you posted has no return clause. It should end with `return $result;` if you want to get the data outside the function.

Comment: +1 as it's a good point, and the OP doesn't appear to have responded.